# Meaning of $f$ being holomorphic on the neighborhood of the unit disc, and Cauchy Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula, holomorphic-functions

What does $f$ is holomorphic on the neighborhood of the unit disc mean?
Does it mean it's holomorphic on the disc or both on&inside the disc?

Also, if $f$ is holomorphic on the neighborhood of the unit disc, why is the Cauchy Theorem leads from the first line to the second line?[image: Cauchy Theorem applied on f]

It would be great if someone could help me out :) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when people say that a function $f$ is holomorphic on a neighborhood of the unit disk, they mean that there is an open set $\Omega$ containing the disk $\{z:|z|\leq 1\}$ such that $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$. Often $\Omega$ is assumed to be connected as well.

To pass from the first line to the second in the equations you included, we must show that
$$ \int_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z-\overline{z}_0^{-1}}\;dz=0 $$

Although you didn't specifically say this, my guess is that $0<|z_0|<1$. Then $|\bar{z}_0^{-1}|=\frac{1}{|z_0|}>1$, and it follows that the function $\frac{f(z)}{z-\overline{z}_0^{-1}}$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of the closed unit disk. Therefore
$$ \int_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z-\overline{z}_0^{-1}}\;dz=0 $$
by Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your guess is perfectly right. Sorry for missing that out. 
I still don't understand why the function $\frac{f(z)}{z-\bar{z}_0^{-1}}$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of the closed unit disk.
Oh is it because the $f(z)$ and $z-\bar{z}_0^{-1}$ are both holomorphic? So the fraction of them becomes holomorphic as well?

Comment: $\frac{f(z)}{z-\overline{z}_0^{-1}}$ is a quotient of holomorphic functions, so is holomorphic unless the denominator is zero, i.e. $z=\overline{z}_0^{-1}$.